# does codeigniter helper library folder should be empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to master codeigniter.
Although I think that everything should work I'm getting following error `Unable to load the requested file: helpers/database_helper.php`

Inside helpers folder there is only index.html file, also inside libraries there is again only index.html. Am I missing something here, I've downloaded package from official code igniter website.

Obviously ci cannot find helper file, I've loaded explicitly as

```
class mydb_model extends CI_Model {
    public function getAll(){     
        $this->load->helper('database');
        $q = $this->db->get('Test', 'desc');        
        if ($q->num_rows() >0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;            
            }
            return $data;
        }        
    }
```

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load the database, use:

```
$this->load->database();
```

Read more [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html).

Comment: should I replace $this->load->helper('database'); with this load->database(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to back out of the application folder and enter the system folder, then the helpers folder to see codeigniters helpers.  There are two "helper" folders.

However, you can go in to application->config and open the autoload.php, then put whatever you want to load in there.

Sidenote: Helpers are basically just php functions that can be called globally.